# slew rate of a mosfet

Tags: transistors, pmos, slew-rate

Is there way to calculate slew rate of following circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPQW6M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Datasheet for Transistor](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/427/sihf9530-102776.pdf)

[Datasheet for Diode](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/1N4148-888354.pdf)

I chose the PMOS and Diode arbitrarily from what I could choose from Circuit Lab.

If VTRIG goes from 5V to 0V, how can I calculate the slew rate (V/us)?

Comment: Uhhh datasheet?

Comment: @Bradman175 I've added link to datasheet

Comment: Now go into dynamic under specifications and look at the delay and rise fall times?

Comment: poor choice of FET for -5V Vgs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A rough approximate is to use the RdsOn for -5V.
- It is guaranteed to be 0.3Ω but that is for -10V @25'C with 7.2A Pulse, width = 300 μs; duty cycle = 2 %.
- your situation is different and vague;

  - Initial conditions :
  - Vcap (unknown )
  - Cap part number (unknown ) and
  - trace inductance (unknown )
  - cap ESR or Dissipation Factor (unknown )
  - Diode ESR 1N4148  0.1W ~ 10ohm ( assumed to be larger than 1nF
  - Cap ESR which is expected to have ESR*C value=T < 0.1us for ceramic
  - The RdsOn starts at a high value due to Vdes =5V and Vgs=-5V and not being a "logic level" gate controlled FET requires a certain amount of calculations from the datasheet below
    [image]

With the slew rate being dV/dt=Ic/C for the cap and Ic = (V+-Vcap)/(RdsOn+ESR(diode)) it becomes highly nonlinear.

But with initial conditions of ESR diode=10, and ESR or RdsOn of FET=10Ω then dropping to 0.34 Ω as Vds drops below 3V.

- Ic=C dV/dt=1e-9 * (5V)/(10Ω+10Ω) and C= 1e-9F for Vds=3~5V

slew rate dV/dt= Ic/C= 5V/20Ω*1e9= = 0.25V/ns

Low confidence in results due to inadequate info.